# Is there a way to subscribe by mail or something else on kernel updates in ubuntu LTS (changelog)

Tags: kernel, updates, email

We use a lot of ubuntu. I would like to be aware of updates that happen with a stable kernel in this distribution, e.g. latest LTS.

How can I receive(setup) push-type notifications (email, messenger, anything else) and read them with morning coffee?

Comment: Of course I know about this site: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/

Comment: You could put a Google Alert on this page: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?showmsg=1